# Due to screen rotation, etc., it is not possible to listen for click events once an activity has been killed

Tags: java, android

I'm monitoring the "EditText" focus event in the main activity. This is listened to by the TaskLoader's Callback, and once the app is launched, it works as expected.

However, if the activity is killed by a screen rotation or something else, the focus events won't work. I inserted the log and checked it, but the event itself does not seem to have been triggered...

Do you find anything wrong with the following source code?

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
...
    private EditText mEditText;

    private final int ASYNC_INIT_TASK_LOADER = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mEditText = findViewById(R.id.edit_text);

        LoaderManager.getInstance(this).restartLoader(
                ASYNC_INIT_TASK_LOADER,
                null,
                new InitTaskLoaderCallback()
        );
    }

    public class InitTaskLoaderCallback implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Long> {
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Loader<Long> onCreateLoader(int id, @Nullable Bundle args) {
            return new InitTaskLoader(MainActivity.this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadFinished(@NonNull Loader<Long> loader, Long data) {
            LoaderManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this).destroyLoader(ASYNC_INIT_TASK_LOADER);

            Log.d("DEBUG", "Passed InitTaskLoaderCallback");

            ...

            mEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
                    Log.d("DEBUG", "onFocusChange");
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoaderReset(@NonNull Loader<Long> loader) {
        }
    }
}
...
```

Comment: You can set the focus state of the corresponding edittext by enabling detection with the onConfigurationChanged method.

Comment: @kzncrda
For example, the same thing happens with killed by OS as well as screen rotation, so onConfigurationChanged may not be able to counteract it.

Comment: Have you tried using your edittext listener outside of the loader?

Comment: @kzncrda
I want to register listeners for a reason, waiting for the loader task to be completed...
can't set up a listener in here?

Comment: Indeed, registering a listener outside of a callback (I tried onCreate) worked as expected, even after a kill... 
But why? I don't know why...